# Motion disable during the night

Tags: cron, motion

I use my RPi to periodically take pictures, both snapshots and of detected motion events. Is there any way to stop motion from taking pictures during the night? For example I imagine this could be done through crontab, but I haven't been able to find any way to control motion through the command line. Any suggestions on how I could control it through crontab, or alternatively other solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [control motion via cron](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/control-motion-via-cron)

Comment: I think you should give more information like the software you use to take snapshots (maybe `motion` but I'm not sure), if you run it at startup (and if so, how), what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Motion supports remote commands via http, documented at [RemoteControlHttp](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/RemoteControlHttp).   You can use wget, curl, or lwp-request in crontab to stop motion at a predetermined time.   Assuming default options in motion.conf, this example will stop motion at 8pm each day:

```
0 20 * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://localhost:8080/0/action/quit
```